# Geocoding a list of thousands of addresses

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, limit

I am new to this forum. I'm not a professional developer but I need to associate the GPS coordinates to a large set of addresses (more than 1000). I developed a simple javascript that makes geocoderequests and display the results in the log. I noticed that after 11 requests it starts returning the "over_query_limit" error. I read about the rate limit of ten requests per second so I inserted a sleep() of 1 seconds between each request and the following but the problem keeps bothering me. Is there anyone who could help me with this issue? 
Thanks, Filippo

Comment: why am I supposed to wait 24 hours? I am sure I didn't exceed the 2500 requests limit per day...was that the reason behind your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try a function that does only one request at the time, and run that function up to 10x per second, using `setInterval`.

Example:

```
//  set some variables
var currentRequest = 0;
var numberOfRequests = 1000;

//  write the function that does one request at the time
function request()
{
    //  request code here, using variable currentRequest

    currentRequest ++;  //  move along one request
}

//  set an interval, so the function runs every tenth of a second (100 ms)
var interval = setInterval(request, 100);

//  and stop the interval if the requests are done
if(currentRequest >= numberOfRequests)
{
    clearInterval(interval);
}
```

Surely, this will takes a few seconds for thousands of requests, but it should avoid the 10 requests per second limit nicely.